# AMD Radeon R5 Graphics Glitches In Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, graphics

My Laptop specs :
AMD A8-6410
Radeon R5 Graphics
4 GB DDR3
500 GB HDD

I removed Windows 8.1 completely & installed Ubuntu 14.04.1
But, the graphics is just too damn slow.

The output of /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p shows :

OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.

OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)

OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    no

Not blacklisted:          yes

GLX fbconfig:             yes

GLX texture from pixmap:  yes

GL npot or rect textures: yes

GL vertex program:        yes

GL fragment program:      yes

GL vertex buffer object:  yes

GL framebuffer object:    yes

GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no

Why Unity 3D is not supported ? Seems like Unity animations are very slow due to this. Can anyone help me out to fix this ?
Do I have to use proprietary drivers ? I am not going to game, all I want is smooth animation so I can work easily.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It requires an additional driver. Go to **Additional Drivers** tab in **Software & Updates** and select "Video Driver for the AMD Graphics..." (second option). Then **Apply changes** and **Restart**.

OR

You can manually download and install linux proprietary driver from **AMD** website. See [url](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86_64). It required some dependency packages. Please go through this [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) for detailed installation procedure.