# How to fix black screen after installing "Video Driver for the AMD Graphics"

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I just followed this discussion [AMD Radeon R5 Graphics Glitches In Ubuntu 14.04.1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/539998/amd-radeon-r5-graphics-glitches-in-ubuntu-14-04-1/908999#908999) to install driver and restart, then I get only black screen after I choose boot option. How can I fix this situation?

I can enter recovery mode, and use vi command to check my `/var/log/dpkg.log` file, but there are too many messages like "install...", "remove...", "status...".

I'm not sure if I just use command `dpkg --remove \*amd64\*` or `dpkg --purge \*amd64\*` to remove them is safe or not.

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Dell Inspiron 14 3459
- AMD Radeon R5 M315 2GB DDR3

In recovery mode, I choose "root" and enter

```
mount -o rw,remount /
apt-get remove fglrx*
```

It looks like remove failed.

[image]

[image]

Does it mean that I need to "enable networking"? I've tried to choose that option in recovery mode, but it will show other error messages and can't open terminal successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first remove the driver that you just installed. Many folks forgot to mention fhat you need to create a config file after installing fglrx driver.

First remove the driver by applying

`sudo apt-get remove fglrx*`

Then reboot the machine. It will be installed xorg driver by default so you may login.

After login you install the driver using AMD's support file that they published for 14.04.

After installing the driver again type this command to set the config file:

`sudo amdconfig --initial`

If you have dual graphics apply this command

`sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial`

After this reboot the machine and the driver will be installed succesfully.

Comment: Hi Egimo, it seems that I can't remove fglrx* successfully. I attached my screen shots, does it mean I need network? If so, how can I trigger my network in recovery mode?

Comment: @Josper I think removing xorg drivers are not a good idea. Can you try `sudo apt-get purge fglrx`. Also if you have cable connection you can write `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xorg-xserver*`

Comment: @Egimo, sorry, I just have a meeting previously. So you mean that use the command apt-get purge fglrx instead of apt-get remove fglrx*?

Comment: @Josper purge will make a complete delete of the package and its dependent packages. You could try it instead of remove

Comment: @Egimo, I'm just a little confused. If I type "apt-get purge fglrx", it will show message "Package 'fglrx' is not installed, so not removed". Does it mean that I've uninstall them? I try to restart my ubuntu normally, it still fail.

Comment: And when I try to install xserver-xorg*, it will show message "Unable to correct problem, you have held broken packages"

Comment: @Josper You can install Fglrx with <code>sudo apt-get install fglrx</code> and after that you can write <code>sudo amdconfig --initial</code> and reboot the machine.